# Luarocks won't let me install luaposix

Tags: lua

I was trying to build luaposix with luarocks. I did it like this:

```
luarocks install luaposix
```

but when process was near to complete, in console I can see following text:

```
Installing https://luarocks.org/luaposix-33.4.0-1.src.rock
./configure LUA='lua5.1.exe' LUA_INCLUDE='-Ic:/lua/include' --prefix='c:\lua\sys
tree/lib/luarocks/rocks/luaposix/33.4.0-1' --libdir='c:\lua\systree/lib/luarocks
/rocks/luaposix/33.4.0-1/lib' --datadir='c:\lua\systree/lib/luarocks/rocks/luapo
six/33.4.0-1/lua' --datarootdir='c:\lua\systree/lib/luarocks/rocks/luaposix/33.4
.0-1' && make clean all

(here is text about command '.' cannot be found)

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

What should I do now? I'm only begginner in installing lua libraries (for me its actually very complicated process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [luaposix](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix) Github page says:

> This is a POSIX binding for LuaJIT, Lua 5.1, 5.2 and 5.3; like most libraries it simply binds to C APIs on the underlying system, so it won't work on non-POSIX systems.

Windows is a non-POSIX system. The error you describe is because the syntax of the `configure` command:

```
./configure LUA='lua5.1.exe' [...]
```

The `./` is not supported in a Windows command prompt. For example:

```
C:\Lua53>./lua
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```